# Google Maps V3 Infobox undefined on polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I have a spoke in my wheels and I am not sure how to sort this out. I have been struggling with it for a couple days and it isn't like a normal infobox as it is not set to a marker rather a polygon which is something new for me. I have polygons that display with data from an XML file and they show up fine. I have searched the web and got it to have the mouseover set up to where you mouseover a polygon the opacity changes and an infobox pops up. Problem is the infobox when it pop up shows "undefined" instead of the html I have set in it to display with data from the XML file.

Here is a link to the test map for example.

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/googlemap_poly.html

Here is a link to the XML file where I am just trying to show the elements events and expires in the info box.

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/warnings_test.xml

This is the code I am working with to create the infoboxes and mouseover events

```
 function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon, html, event, expires)
  {

       var html = "<strong>" + event + "</strong>";

        eventWarnings.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});

       google.maps.event.addListener(eventWarnings, 'mouseover', function(e) {
             var latLng = e.latLng;
                 this.setOptions({fillOpacity:80});
                 polygon.infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
                 polygon.infoWindow.open(map);
        });

      google.maps.event.addListener(eventWarnings, 'mouseout', function() {
             this.setOptions({fillOpacity:0.35});
             polygon.infoWindow.close();
    });
}

      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(/* omitted for brevity */);
                    attachPolygonInfoWindow(eventWarnings);

          eventWarnings.setMap(map);
       }
  });
```

I am pretty sure it is something easy I am overlooking but I haven't been able to find anything that pertains to my issue. I am just lucky I got the infobox to show at all as I have learned it's tricky since polygons don't have a true center and they are not set up like you would with a marker which I can handle.

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your attachPolygonInfoWindow function with 4 argument, but only provide one when you call it:

```
 // definition
 function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon, html, event, expires)
 ...

 // call
 attachPolygonInfoWindow(eventWarnings);
```

Probably you want (I don't see the html or expires parameters being used):

```
attachPolygonInfoWindow(eventWarnings, "", event, null);
```

The other option would be to change the definition to:

```
 // definition
 function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon, event, expires)
```

and the call to (assuming you are going to use "expires" for something):

```
attachPolygonInfoWindow(eventWarnings, event, expires);
```

As it doesn't look like you need to pass in that parameter (event is serving the function that I would expect it to serve).

Also, FYI, you have a "hanging comma" in your alertColors.js which make IE unhappy...

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/mesquiteweather_net_PolygonInfoWindows.html)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I provided 4 arguments in the function but I was unable to get the polygons to display when I tried to add more than one to the call. So in order to get an example I had it setup like that. The only thing I had different before is I was missing the "" which I knew it was something small. Your example now shows the event titles but when I tried to add expires and it doesn't load. I have var html = "<strong>" + event + "</strong>"; to format the style but when I add that to the call it kills the map. Do I need to set up a var for expires to get the element tag by name?

Comment: You don't _have_ to create a variable to get the value of that from the XML, it just would be consistent with the rest of the code.  Where do you expect the value for "expires" to come from?  Also, if you aren't passing anything in to your `attachPolygonInfoWindow` function in the html parameter, you can remove it (rather than passing in a placeholder...)

Comment: see the new example for a simplified attachPolygonInfoWindow with the expires data.